# API-platform, protected root, trying to get client-generator working

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I have an api-platform project. The roots are all protected by a login.

http://localhost:8888/docs does show the API documentation.

I kept getting 401 on the client generator, so, I made the following changes to security.yml

```
api:
    pattern:   ^/
    security: false
    provider: db_provider
    stateless: true
    anonymous: true
    # guard:
    #     authenticators:
    #         - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
```

That however generated a strange error:

```
generate-api-platform-client --generator vue http://localhost:8888 /src --resource legal_types
Error: Unable to find the URL for "http://localhost:8888/docs.jsonld#Entrypoint/user".
    at _loop (/Users/xxx/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/@api-platform/api-doc-parser/lib/hydra/parseHydraDocumentation.js:437:17)
    at fetchEntrypointAndDocs.then._promise2.default.reject.api._Api2.default.resources (/Users/xxx/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/@api-platform/api-doc-parser/lib/hydra/parseHydraDocumentation.js:459:20)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Answer (score 0):

`pattern: ^/` matches nothing.

If you want to match anything you should go with `^.*$` but if you need all application to be under a secured firewall but only docs to be accessible in anonymous way, just put as first rule this `pattern: ^docs` and place everything else (`/.*$`) under secured firewall.

Comment: docs:
            pattern:   ^/docs
            anonymous: true

This is higher up in the file, so I guess that applies? doesn't affect anything (still under firewall in the yml of course)